# Cambiar el login por defecto login.blade a mi header Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, login

Estoy tratando de cambiar mi login de la pagina por defecto cuando uno hace make:auth (login.blade.php) al cambiarlo a mi header pero no entiendo por que no funciona, si aparte de los estilos para colocarlo en el header todo esta igual al original en el formulario, leí la documentación oficial pero no vi nada que me dijera que solo se podía hacer login en (login.blade.php) en esa pagina en particular.

Puedo logear en el login por defecto (el que sale al hacer artisan make:auth ) hay puedo acceder de manera normal, pero sí trato de logear por mi header modificado no pasa nada solo hace como si carga algo pero no vuelve a la pagina (ni aun copiando el código original del form del login en el dropdown de mi nuevo header pasa algo).

Este es el login por defecto de laravel

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>
                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

este login funciona bien es el por defecto (login.blade.php)

Este es el fragmento de header al que intento incluirle el login (nlogin.blade.php)

```
<li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}

      <div class="{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="email" class="control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
        <div class="">
          <input id="email" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="email" name="user[username]" size="30" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus/>
          @if ($errors->has('email'))
              <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
              </span>
          @endif
        </div>

      </div>

        <div class="{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <label for="password" class="control-label">Password</label>
          <div class="">
            <input id="password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="password" required size="30" class="form-control"/>
            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"  style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me </label>
        </div>

        <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" />
        <input class="btn btn-danger" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px; margin-top:5px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Registrarse" onclick="location.href='{{ url('/register') }}';" />
    </form>
</div>
</li>
```

Ese es el fragmento de login que incluyo en un drowdown en (navbar.blade.php) aqui el fragmento donde lo incluyo (funciona bien)

```
                  @if (Auth::guest())
                        @include('shared.nlogin')
                  @else
                      <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                              {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                          </a>

                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                              <li>
                                  <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                      onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                               document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                      Logout
                                  </a>

                                  <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                      {{ csrf_field() }}
                                  </form>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </li>
                  @endif
```

No entiendo que puede ser lo que pasa puede ser algo en configuración que solo recibe de login.blade?. Llegue a un momento dado copiar en nlogin.blade todo el contenido de login y igual no funciono tengo incluido todo lo que esta en el layou.app (que es la navbar que te hace por defecto laravel cuando creas el login) y igual no funciona.

Comment: Hola JLeo, puedes poner signos de puntuacion y separar el texto en párrafos para que sea más claro ? Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

No deberias tener problema en cambiar el header. Compruebas que csrf token lo tengas incluido en el código. Aún así, si dejas el error que te da será más fácil poder ayudarte

Comment: No me deja error solo se recarga la pagina y no logea. Si lo hago desde el login si me reenvia a mi pagina principal (lo configure asi) y me coloca en el header el usuario que logeo y todo normal

Comment: Has comprobado las rutas al middleware?